# ui-router clear cache programmatically

Tags: caching, typescript, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have dynamically changing template when orientation has changed.

For that reason I've disable cache, but it's very very slow on even very powerful devices.

For that reason I need to cache the both views, but still be able to see the template changing, how can I implement this?

```js
    $stateProvider.state("app.timesheet", {
      cache: false,
      url: "/timesheet",
      views: {
        "menuContent": {
          templateUrl: () => {
            var orientation: number = ( < any > window).orientation;
            if (orientation === 90 || orientation === -90) { // Landscape
              return "views/timesheet/landscape.html"
            } else if (orientation === 0 || orientation === 180 || orientation === -180) { // Portrait
              return "views/timesheet/portrait.html";
            }
          },
          controller: "TimesheetController"
        }
      },
      data: {
        requireAuthorize: true
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The templateUrl can be a function. And in the function also add an "else" block to return the default template. Like below:

```
$stateProvider.state("app.timesheet", {
      url: "/timesheet",
      views: {
        "menuContent": {
          templateUrl: function() {
            var orientation: number = ( < any > window).orientation;
            if (orientation === 90 || orientation === -90) { // Landscape
              return "views/timesheet/landscape.html"
            } else if (orientation === 0 || orientation === 180 || orientation === -180) { // Portrait
              return "views/timesheet/portrait.html";
            }else {
               //return default template
            }
          },
          controller: "TimesheetController"
        }
      },
      data: {
        requireAuthorize: true
      }
    });
```